# Import product ratings

Tags: magento-1.9, import, importexport, review, ratings

Is it possible to import the star ratings in a CSV import on Magento?
I know I can import/export the reviews, but these exports do not include the star rating (Detailed Rating)

Can someone point me in the direction of a Data Profile that will allow for the import and export of reviews including the ratings please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this extension

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/product-review-import-export.html

This extension allowed to import/export reviews and ratings in csv format from magento dataflow profile .

Or alternatively you can use this code to get ratings of review

```
 $ratingCollection = Mage::getModel('rating/rating_option_vote')
                    ->getResourceCollection()
                    ->setReviewFilter($review->getId()); // your review id
```

This will give you rating collection of review

Comment: I'm using that extension currently, it only seems to export the reviews and does not bring the Star Ratings with it. What file would I add that $ratingCollection code to?

Comment: option_id is field for ratings

Comment: Ah, got it. Misleading column title - I've renamed this to ratings.